# Which one to buy to print photos at home: photo printer or inkjet printer?

Tags: printing, printer

I want to print photos at home with good quality. I read online that an inkjet printer prints photos as well with good quality. Please suggest me which to buy and why? I want to use that printer as a regular document printer as well.

Comment: Most 'photo printers' are inkjet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many good inkjet printers that will produce good results. I think this site would like questions that are slightly longer lived than a specific recommendation of a brand or model number, and I see related topics on the right that will probably answer your question better, like this one: [What should I look for in a printer for photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15232/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-printer-for-photos?rq=1)

All that said, I can tell you what I use: an Epson 1430. It is a very decent printer for the money. Bear in mind that ink is usually where the manufacturers make their money, but the Claria inks are quite good as well. I use an entirely different process for black and white prints with my 1430, but there are many folks that use it in its default configuration with good results.

You will probably get better answers here if you are more specific about the type of photos you would like to print, and the sizes and type of print media you are interested in.

Comment: One warning: Epsons like to be used or they clog, so they're not the best option for occasional use. I use more ink in head cleaning than printing now I rarely print photos at home

Answer (score 0):

I use HP deskjet 9800 that has quadrichrome photographic inks kit, it is a professional office printer but is versatile and does really good photo prints even in A3 paper size.

Answer (score -2):

You can certainly get reasonably results with an inkjet printer, but the price per. picture is quite high and the quality of pictures bad - for my liking - when using an ordinary inkjet printer! On a daily basis I work with flexleasing, and we must use the images immediately. We use a mini photo printer, it uses photo sheets as a polarid photo. It delivers beautiful, natural images and cheaper to operate than the more expensive inkjet cartridges.

My advice is, make a Google search: "mini photo printer".

Then find a model that can print directly from you camera / device. Good luck with you pictures.